# Determine $P (A ∪ (\overline{\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C})})$ in the following case

Tags: probability, statistics

Determine $P (A ∪ (\overline{\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C})})$ in the following case:

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are incompatible two by two and $P (A) = 3/8$

I did this:

$P (A ∪ (\overline{\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C})}) =P(A∪B)∩P(A∪C)=P(A∪B)+P(A∪C)-P(A∪B∪C)$

but I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is a bit confusing to me. I would do this:
\begin{align*}
P\left(\!A\cup\overline{\left(\overline{B}\cup\overline{C}\right)}\,\right)&=P(\!A\cup(B\cap C))\\
&=P(A\cup\varnothing)\\
&=P(A)\\
&=\frac38.
\end{align*}

Comment: $B∩C=∅$ because B and C are incompatible?

Comment: Exactly, that's how I read it.

Comment: if I have $something∩0$ what is it equal to?

Comment: The null set behaves like this: $A\cup\varnothing=A$ for all sets $A,$ and $A\cap\varnothing=\varnothing$ for all sets $A.$

Comment: If $P(A) = 1/2, P(B ∩ C) = 1/4, P(A ∩ C) = 0$ how do I find $P (A ∪ (\overline{\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C})})$?

Comment: Hmm. You'd have $P(A\cup(B\cap C))=P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C))=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)-P((A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C))=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)-P(A\cap B\cap C).$ You'd need to know $P(A\cap B)$ to finish, as well as $P(A\cap B\cap C).$

Comment: isn't it $A∪(B∩C)=(A∪B)∩(A∪C)$?

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91610/discussion-between-user649882-and-adrian-keister).

Comment: Going back here for the $\LaTeX.$ Draw a Venn diagram, and you will see that if $P(A\cap C)=0,$ it follows that $P(A\cup(B\cap C))=P(A)+P(B\cap C)=\frac34.$

Comment: Now if we now that $P(\overline{A} ∩ (\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C}) = 1/3$? It's the last one I promise :)

Comment: I would draw the Venn diagram and figure out what that region corresponds to. What do you get?

Comment: it comprends everything except $A$ together with $B∩C$

Comment: ... which is the exact opposite of $P (A ∪ (\overline{\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C})})$, so $P (A ∪ (\overline{\overline{B} ∪ \overline{C})}) = 1 - 1/3 = 0.67$